# GEO IP based content display

Tags: javascript

I have added the below code into this page so that I can display specific content when people come from India. But it is not working as needed. In the head section

```
    <script>
            $.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    if(response.country_code=='US'||response.country_code=='UK'||response.country_code=='IN'){
        document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
}, "jsonp");
        </script>
        <style>
            #US {display:none;}
            #UK {display:none;}
            #IN {display:none;}
        </style>
```

& in the body section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                        <div id="ip">Loading...</div>
<div id="country_code"></div>
<div id="US">THE US</div>
<div id="UK">THE UK</div>
<div id="IN">THE IN</div>
```

Please help with the correct code. This can be at present viewed [here](http://richesd.xyz/--simple-website-design.html)

Comment: _"But it is not working as needed"_ - And we are supposed to know why it _"is not working"_ because of what exactly? Are there any errors (in the console)? What happens? What doesn't happen? What happens instead?

Comment: When we load the page say from India nothing shows up that was meant for that country. - THE IN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use jQuery's API before it's loaded. Just move the jQuery CDN to the top of your embedded code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function(response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    
    if (response.country_code == 'US'
      ||response.country_code == 'UK'
      ||response.country_code == 'IN') {
      document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
  }, "jsonp");
</script>
```